# Small Jquery Pager/Slider

Tags: jquery

I have been busy creating a Jquery Slider and ran into an unusual problem. I have two main functions for sliding called slideFromLeft and slideFromRight. Both take an integer as parameter to indicate to which slide number it has to "slide", either from the right or from the left. This all works perfectly.

Now, where the problem comes in: I've been trying to add next() and previous() functions, both making use of the slideFromLeft and slideFromRight functions, respectively, ie. like this:

```
self.slideFromLeft(Math.max(0, self.current - 1));
```

After calling either one of these functions, the first time works, but neither of them want to work a second time, while the slideFromLeft and slideFromRight functions still work as normal.

The console error I am getting when calling the next() or prev() functions a second time is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'next' of object [object Object] is not a
>   function

I've created a JSFiddle so you can test and see the result for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/HCzbW/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using `self.next` and `self.prev` as both a function and variable to store an int.

```
self.prev = 0;
...
self.next = 0;
...
```

and

```
self.next = function () {
    self.slideFromRight(
        Math.min(self.last, self.current + 1)
    );
}

self.prev = function () {
    self.slideFromLeft(
        Math.max(0, self.current - 1)
    );
}
```

---

the problem occurred in these lines

```
self.slideFromLeft = function (num) {
  ...
  self.prev = self.current;
  self.next = num;
  ...
}
```

and

```
self.slideFromRight = function (num) {
  ...
  self.prev = self.current;
  self.next = num;
  ...
}
```

---

if you rename your functions to `nextSlide` and `prevSlide`, respectively, your Slider will work again.

```
self.nextSlide = function () {
    self.slideFromRight(
        Math.min(self.last, self.current + 1)
    );
}

self.prevSlide = function () {
    self.slideFromLeft(
        Math.max(0, self.current - 1)
    );
}
```

and your html to

```
<a href="#" onclick="list.prevSlide()">Prev</a>
<a href="#" onclick="list.nextSlide()">Next</a>
```

You can see it here in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/HCzbW/2/